# First recipe : helloworld exercise

Tags: openrewrite

Working on the new recipe which is the helloworld exercise in the openrewrite docs .Getting an error while running the recipe . Any help will be appreciated .

https://docs.openrewrite.org/authoring-recipes/writing-a-java-refactoring-recipe

rewrite.yml

```
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.escuela.openrewrite.SayHelloRecipe
recipeList:
  - com.escuela.openrewrite.SayHelloRecipe:
      fullyQualifiedClassName: com.escuela.openrewrite.FooBar
```

https://github.com/escuelatech/openrewrite/tree/main/firstORRecepie

I have executed the test-class successfully but there was no expected output .

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: The post does have a minimally reproducible example @Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YAML recipe name needs to be distinct from the recipe in the `recipeList`. For example:

```
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.escuela.openrewrite.SayHelloFooBar
recipeList:
  - com.escuela.openrewrite.SayHelloRecipe:
      fullyQualifiedClassName: com.escuela.openrewrite.FooBar
```

Notice that name is `SayHelloFooBar`.